# Dynamic variable name inside a function AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have the following problem:

I have a function which receives multiple variables:

```
function test( fooValue:String, foobar1:String, foobar2:String, goobar1:String, goobar2:String ) {
//using the values statically
mytext1.text = foobar1;
mytext2.text = foobar2;
mytext3.text = goobar1;
mytext4.text = goobar2;

if ( goobar1 = "problem" ) {
    myProblem.text = this["foo" + fooValue] + this["goo" + fooValue];
}
}
//now here's an example call
test( "bar1","first value ","second value ", "another value", "yet another value");
```

given the fact that fooValue has "bar1" on the above call, how can I make myProblem.text to display " first value another value"

this[ "foo" + fooValue] gives me undefined

- edited the question and trying to be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to use _either_ the foobar1 or the foobar2 value or them _both_ inside the function? Can you provide more detail to what you want to do, because your question is very ambiguous with such small detail to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @joncys 
The function wrote above is a simplified one. I'll try below to extend it maybe you'll get my point. I will use both values in that function STATICALLY of course. But also in a certain part of the function I want to dynamically tell which value would be used, because the call would be from an external application. Now let's rewrite the code:

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
function test( fooValue:String, foobar1:String, foobar2:String, goobar1:String, goobar2:String ) {
//using the values statically
mytext1.text = foobar1;
mytext2.text = foobar2;
mytext3.text = goobar1;
mytext4.text = goobar2;

if ( goobar1 == "problem" ) {
    myProblem.text = this["foo" + fooValue] + this["goo" + fooValue];
}
}
//now here's an example call
test( "bar1","first value ","second value ", "another value", "yet another value")
```

Notice the change? Its the extra `=` in the `if(goobar1...` line.

`goobar1 = "problem"` sets the value of goobar1.

`goobar1 == "problem"` returns whether the value of goobar1 is "problem"

Rookie mistake, made sometimes by experienced hands too :)

**Furthermore**

`this["foo" + fooValue]` is equivalent to `this.foobar1` (which is invalid since the `this` object does not have any property called `foobar1`)

You do it like this:

```
switch(fooValue) {
    case "bar1":
        myProblem.text = foobar1 + goobar1;
        break;
    case "bar2":
        myProblem.text = foobar2 + goobar2;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Actually the typo with equal sign was only in this example...It's not the actual function I use. I thought I can somehow get rid of switch/case scenario but if there's no way around I will use this solution.